# Approximating the 5 numbers making up an average.

Tags: approximation, average, means

I'm looking at emails handled in the workplace and overall have worked out an average handling time of 387 seconds. There are 5 different types of emails that go into this average and there volumes are below;

Email 1 - 12,081
Email 2 - 7,453
Email 3 - 4,475
Email 4 - 2,808
Email 5 - 2,674

Now, assuming each type of email takes the same time to handle is there a way I can work backwards through this and calculate an average handling time for each type?

I know it would be a case of best fit and any help anyone could give me would be great.

Cheers in advance

Ben

Comment: There is woefully inadequate information to conclude much of anything without making *drastic* assumptions for which there is no basis for.

Comment: Multiply the average handling time per message by the total number of each type of message.

Comment: I would appear JMoravitz and David G. Stork are interpreting this line differently "each type of email takes the same time to handle". If this means (exactly as it says) that all emails take the same time on average, no matter the type, then David is correct: multiply the average handling time per email by the average volume for each type. But that is obvious enough, Like JMoravitz, i suspect you mean that each email in a type takes the same amount of time, but that time differs between types. Then JMoravitz is correct. There isn't enough information.